# LBClient getRequestSpecificRetryHandler ignores Ribbon client configuration

Tags: java, spring, spring-cloud

I am having hard time setting the `MaxAutoRetriesNextServer` and `MaxAutoRetries` properties when using  a Feign client with Spring Cloud Netflix. I need these because when having a service cluster with several instances, some of which may go down together, I want Ribbon to try next server until it finds one up.

The service I am targeting from my Feign client is named *quote-service* and it is correctly registered with Eureka. I can also reach it no problems using the elastic IP.

My `application.yml` configuration specific to ribbon looks like this:

```
quote-service:
  ribbon:
    OkToRetryOnAllOperations: true
    MaxAutoRetriesNextServer: 50
    MaxAutoRetries: 50
```

However, when I look at what happens when the `com.netflix.client.AbstractLoadBalancerAwareClient.getRequestSpecificRetryHandler(S, IClientConfig)` is invoked, the client configuration I set is ignored completely.

```
  @Override
  public RequestSpecificRetryHandler getRequestSpecificRetryHandler(
      RibbonRequest request, IClientConfig requestConfig) {
    if (clientConfig.get(CommonClientConfigKey.OkToRetryOnAllOperations, false)) {
      return new RequestSpecificRetryHandler(true, true, this.getRetryHandler(), requestConfig);
    }
    if (!request.toRequest().method().equals("GET")) {
      return new RequestSpecificRetryHandler(true, false, this.getRetryHandler(), requestConfig);
    } else {
      return new RequestSpecificRetryHandler(true, true, this.getRetryHandler(), requestConfig);
    }
  }
```

My setting are present in the `clientConfig` variable but that is not taken into consideration at all. I assume at some point `com.netflix.loadbalancer.LoadBalancerContext.setRetryHandler(RetryHandler)` should be invoked with the proper `RetryHandler` but it never happens.

UPDATE:

I checked how `LBClient` is constructed and I believe the main issue lies in there.

```
LBClient(ILoadBalancer lb, IClientConfig clientConfig) {
    super(lb, clientConfig);
    this.setRetryHandler(RetryHandler.DEFAULT);
    this.clientConfig = clientConfig;
    connectTimeout = clientConfig.get(CommonClientConfigKey.ConnectTimeout);
    readTimeout = clientConfig.get(CommonClientConfigKey.ReadTimeout);
  }
```

The `retryHandler` is being overriden with a default one which does not carry the values I specify. However, I see no way of solving this other than fiddling with bean definitions myself. Is it intended behavior? If not, what am I doing wrong?

UPDATE 2:

I filed an issue for this.

https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/issues/505

Comment: By the way, Spring Cloud beans/classes of reference (i.e. where this configuration is done) are `SpringLBClientFactory` and `FeignRibbonClientAutoConfiguration`

Comment: Will you open an issue?

Comment: BTW, it's a problem in vanilla feign as well.

Comment: I see that your update code is in vanilla feign.  I don't see RibbonLoadBalancer used anywhere.

Comment: I didn't open an issue since I wanted to be sure I'm not misunderstanding the code. But I can surely do so.

Comment: @spencergibb Yeah, I noticed I was debugging through vanilla feign. What is happening is that, even if I define my `@RibbonClient` configuration, when I actually use the feign client to perform a request that will use vanilla `RibbonClient` to execute the request. Internally it invokes your `CachingLBClientFactory` and `SpringLBClientFactory`

Answer (score 0):

I am providing a workaround. It is not necessarily a clean approach but it works.

I personally believe the problem lies in the Netflix constructor of `LBClient` that overrides the `RetryHandler` set correctly by `com.netflix.loadbalancer.LoadBalancerContext.initWithNiwsConfig(IClientConfig)`.

That said I created a new `LBClientFactory` which is simply an extension of the `CachingLBClientFactory` which takes care of overriding (once again) the retry handler with the appropriate configuration.

Here is the code:

```
/**
 * Temporary workaround to make sure {@link RetryHandler} is created according to defined client
 * configuration.
 * 
 * @author Marco Lenzo
 *
 */
public class CustomLBClientFactory extends SpringLBClientFactory {

    @Autowired
    private SpringClientFactory factory;



    /**
     * @param delegate
     */
    public CustomLBClientFactory(SpringClientFactory factory) {
        super(factory);
        this.factory = factory;
    }


    @Override
    public LBClient create(String clientName) {
        LBClient client = super.create(clientName);
        IClientConfig config = factory.getClientConfig(clientName);
        client.setRetryHandler(new DefaultLoadBalancerRetryHandler(config));
        return client;
    }

}
```

Now all it remains is to create the Client with my new factory. I sticked to Spring's approach. Define the following beans in a configuration class.

```
    @Autowired
    private SpringClientFactory factory;



    @Bean
    public CustomLBClientFactory customLBClientFactory() {
        return new CustomLBClientFactory(factory);
    }


    @Bean
    public CachingLBClientFactory cachingLBClientFactory() {
        return new CachingLBClientFactory(customLBClientFactory());
    }


    @Bean
    public Client feignRibbonClient() {
        return RibbonClient.builder().lbClientFactory(cachingLBClientFactory()).build();
    }
```

Happy days :)